# Function parameter Undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely frustrated by a couple of functions in my code. I have a couple of functions that fire when a user clicks on a link.
The parameter is correctly sent to both function but when the user clicks the link for `detailplace` I get a reference error, that `SomeName` is undefined. The function detail seems to work without a problem. Why does `detail` work but `detailplace` does not?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:detail(123456);">Details</a>
<a href="javascript:detailplace(SomeName);">Details</a>
```

Javascript

```
function detail(property) {
    var summaryhtml = '<iframe src="' + URL + property + '" width="340px" height="400px" frameborder="0" class="sum_frame"></iframe>';
    document.getElementById('itab1').innerHTML = summaryhtml;
}

function detailplace(place) {
    var summaryhtml = '<iframe src="' + URL + place + '" width="340px" height="400px" frameborder="0" class="sum_frame"></iframe>';
    document.getElementById('itab1').innerHTML = summaryhtml;
}
```

I took your advice and edited the code to include quotes. The problem is that I'm construting the links in javascript. SomeName is defined elsewhere as a string.

```
link = '<a href="javascript:detailplace(&quot;';
link += SomeName;
link += '&quot;)";>Site Details</a>';
```

What is the right way to escape the quotes within quotes within quotes so I can send the string as a parameter?

Comment: @artemvyshniakov you got me going in the right direction. Then I figured out that the quotes do not need to be javascript escaped but html escaped. I updated the code above to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap `SomeName` with `quotes`:

```
<a href="javascript:detailplace('SomeName');">Details</a>
```

When you pass it without quotes `javascript` thinks that it is variable that is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`SomeName` above is being used as a *variable* not as a *string*.  You are missing quotes.

```
<a href="javascript:detailplace('SomeName');">Details</a>
```

Without quotes, it's looking for a variable called `SomeName` that will hold the name of the place you want to fill.  Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

If `SomeName` is not a variable defined previously, but it is the actual literal text you want to pass to the method, then you need to put it in quotes.

```
javascript:detailplace('SomeName');
```